# Replace nth word in sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a function that get string, I'm looking for a way to format the 3rd word (which is number, that i want to format it with comma). any idea how to do it?
should be something like that:

```
function formatNumber(txt){
    return txt.replace(3rd-word, formatNumber(3rd-word));
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just matching the first set of numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by "word"?  In many languages, words are not separated by spaces so finding word boundaries [is not trivial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the n-th word from the sentence by splitting it up and executing a replace on the word index as specified.

Here is a demo for the code below: <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/Z5cqU/)</kbd>

```
var sentence = "Total is 123456789!"

var formatNumber = function(value) {
    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var replaceWord = function(sentence, pos, formatterFunction) {
    var matches = sentence.match(/(\b[^\s]+\b)/g);
    if (pos < 0 && pos >= matches.length) {
        throw "Index out of bounds: " + pos;
    }
    var match = matches[pos];
    var bounded = new RegExp('\\b' + match + '\\b');
    return sentence.replace(bounded, formatterFunction(match));
};

console.log(replaceWord(sentence, 2, formatNumber)); // Total is 123,456,789!
```

Comment: That will not replace the third word, it will replace the first occurance of the third word. Try the sentence `"Busses with us in them"`...

Comment: It still doesn't replace the third word, it replaces the first occurance of the third word.

Comment: Why `formatterFunction.call(undefined, match)` rather than the simpler `formatterFunction(match)`?

Comment: Try the sentence `"Num12345678 and 34567"`, and you get the result `"Num1234,5678 and 34567"` rather than `"Num12345678 and 34,567"`.

Comment: Added: `RegExp('\\b' + match + '\\b');`

Answer (score 0):

Match any word that consists of digits, and format it:

```
txt = txt.replace(/\b(\d+)\b/g, format);
```

using a formatting function, for example:

```
function format(s) {
  var r = '';
  while (s.length > 3) {
    r = ',' + s.substr(s.length - 3) + r;
    s = s.substr(0, s.length - 3);
  }
  return s + r;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/5yA62/

Comment: This will match only the `1` in `-1.2345e9` which might not be what is expected when the OP is looking for "a number."

Comment: @MikeSamuel: That's possible, it's not clear from the question. That limitation is mentioned in the first sentence of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into parts.

- Create a function that transforms your word into the format you want.
- Split your sentence into words.
- Run that function against the appropriate word.
- Put the words back into a sentence.

This does not solve your problem.  You would still need to find a way to format the number as you choose, but it solves a similar problem of uppercasing the third word:

```
var transformNth = function(n, fn) {
    return function(arr) {
        arr[n] = fn(arr[n]);
        return arr;
    }
};

var makeWords = function(sentence) {return sentence.split(" ");};

var upperCase = function(word) {return word.toUpperCase();}

var transformSentence = function(sentence) {
    // index 2 is the third word
    return transformNth(2, upperCase)(makeWords(sentence)).join(" ");
}

transformSentence("I have a function that get string");
//=> "I have A function that get string"
transformSentence("I'm looking for a way to format the 3rd word");
//=> "I'm looking FOR a way to format the 3rd word"
transformSentence("which is number");
//=> "which is NUMBER"
transformSentence("that i want to format it with comma");
//=> "that i WANT to format it with comma"
transformSentence("any idea how to do it?");
//=> "any idea HOW to do it?"
transformSentence("should be something like that");
//=> "should be SOMETHING like that"
```

It might have problems if your sentences have some more complicated structure than single whitespace separation of words that you want to maintain...